# The import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorAttributes cannot be resolved

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I've generated a Spring Boot web application using `Spring Initializer`, `embedded Tomcat`, `Thymeleaf template engine`, and package as an executable JAR file.

Technologies used:

Spring Boot 2.0.0.M6 , Java 8, maven

but even I have this dependency in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I got this compilation error in my project:

```
 The import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorAttributes cannot be  resolved
 The import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorController cannot be resolved
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Latest version spring boot doesn't contain this jars.Can you do Ctrl+Shift+T then check whether this class is there or not

Answer (score 10):

Try to import ErrorController from

> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.error.ErrorController

and for ErrorAttributes

> import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.error.ErrorAttributes;